# css tooltip link not working

Tags: css, tooltip

I am using this code to show a tooltip on hovering a link:

```
<span id="zing" class="zing-wrapper"><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="tooltip">Keyword<span>This is description here</span></a></span>
```

The tooltip works but when I click on the link, it does not work. Please help. 
I have put the code in js fiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/y9gb6LLj/

Comment: `it does not work` - can you clarify?

Comment: Hyperlink not working. When I click on keyword, it leads to nowhere.

Comment: Hyperlinks don't work in jsfiddle do they unless you Ctrl-Click = http://jsfiddle.net/y9gb6LLj/3/

Comment: When I click on the lion at "Hindustani Classical Music" (fourth line) it does not work.

Comment: I suspect this is because the parent doesn't have position relative and so the positioned span is sitting on top of the link.

Comment: If you remove all the tooltip code from that snippet on your real site the link still does not work (remove all the classes and id). This makes me think that somewhere in your site you stop links from being clickable.

This might be by returning "false" from an event that is also called on that click event or by doing something like e.preventDefault or e.stopPropogation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi jsfiddle uses frame to display resulting code and browser will prevent document.location.href behavior inside the frame. Your code is working as expected to me, copy your code and paste into html file, open it in browser and click your link, you'll redirected to google.